# Jquery Form | Validate form before upload bar is visible

Tags: php, jquery, forms

**Plugins**: Jquery.form.js | Jquery.js

**Explanation**
I would like to validate the **title** and **description** before the loading bar is going to be displayed. In the php that the Jquery submits to I check that the title is more than 3 characters and less than 80, ect. If all of this information is correct the upload script will run but if it is not the php will die and an appropriate error response will be displayed.

The problem is that the loading bar shows the loading progress of the entire request and not just the upload process, this is fine but before I want the loading bar to be displayed I would like to be able to validate the text fields in php.

If you think this could be done in a better manner could you please elaborate.

**JS**

```
function noteUpload() {
    var options = {
        beforeSend: function() {
            // set everything to 0
        },
        data: 
        {
            title: $('#uploadNoteTitle').val(),
            description: $('#uploadNoteDescription').val()
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            //Over here I show the loading bar and let it update with "percentComplete"
        },
        success: function() {

        },
        complete: function(response) {
            //Over here i receive the response and show the error messages if there are any.
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you very much!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to validate title and description and end of the function if validations are true call the noteUpload function:

```
function validateForm(){
    // validate script
    if(true == validation){
          noteUpload()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some form of validation within the

```
beforeSubmit
```

callback. If it fails, simply return false and the form will not be posted. As an example lets say you are using jquery.validate (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
var options = {    
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {              
        if ( !$form.valid() ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

If you insist on doing server side validation, add an AJAX method to the callback.

```
var options = {    
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {    
        var valid = false;  

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'validation.php',
            async: false,
            data : $form.serialize(),
            success : function(isValid) {
                if ( isValid) {
                    valid = true
                }
            }
        }).then(function(){
            if ( !valid ) {
                return false;
            }           
        });
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would a user be able to edit the javascript so that the validation does not need to occur?

Comment: Yes, so maybe an alternative would be updating the valid variable to read a PHP session. e.g. <?php echo 'var valid = "'.json_encode($_SESSION['valid']).'";'; Then if the form is valid, update the session in PHP